# Listen to events on elements loaded into a div from an external file

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'm working on a project combining `HTML` and `JQuery`. There is an event that couses a replace of a `div` with a new `div` from an external html file(using `load('some.html #someDiv'`)).

So far so good, the problem begins when I'm trying to listen to an event(`click` if it matters)of an img that is a part of the new `div`.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I didn't defined the click event of that img in the `ready` function because the image warn't exist at the time in the page.

Anyway nothing I could think of to solve this didn't seem to work..Thanks for the helpers

Comment: do you have any code or error where this is may be happening?

Comment: You want to know about **event delegation** http://lab.distilldesign.com/event-delegation/

Comment: Is your problem that it will not bind the handler to the newly loaded elements? (i.e. will it bind the handler successfully to elements that have already been loaded?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','#newDiv img',function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('click','.someNevDiv img', function() {
    // Code on click
});
```

With your code :

```
$("#newDiv").click(function() { onNewDivClicked(); });
```

Should be :

```
$(document).on('click', '#newDiv', function() {
    onNewDivClicked();
});
```

Comment: In the same place you would put a regular `$(element).click()` event. Generally in `$(document).ready(function() { // here });` :)

Comment: thats what I originally tried. It look like this:
`$("#newDiv").click(function() {
  onNewDivClicked();
 });`
The problem is(I think) that there is no 'newDiv' div in the page when the ready function is being called

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the click after you've added the element:

i.e. according to jquery docs here:
http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $('#result img').bind( 'click', function(){
        alert( 'this is fired on a click event on images inside of #result' );
    });
});
```